# Import CSV, show formatted hyperlinks, =Hyperlink(..,..)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-import-csv

Based on a csv import, I would like to show formatted hyperlinks. There is a formula `=HYPERLINK( "www.google.com" ; "Search Google" )` that does this, but is there any way to include this in a csv import?

This csv line does not work:

```
"test","=HYPERLINK(""""www.google.com"""";""""Search Google"""")"
```

I can manually change the spreadsheet after the input, but I would like to base everything on the csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been searching the internet and found out that there's no way to do that in Google Spreadsheet. I did however created a fairly simple work-a-round:

1. Prepare the following CSV line:
   `test,'=&*HYPERLINK(C1;E1),www.google.com,"Search Google"`
2. Go to the Edit menu and select *Find & Replace*:

   [image]
3. Enter the following:

   [image]
4. The formula will be recognised and accepts the references.

Adding the special characters (**&***) will make it very unlikely that other "fields" are affected by the "Find & Replace" function.

Comment: I was afraid it would be something like this, did you find any documentation stating that it is not possible?

Comment: No. I've uploaded many variations, down loaded them and uploaded them again. Together with your research, I'm pretty sure it isn't possible.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me, via file -> import -> upload:

**contents of test.csv:**

```
=HYPERLINK("www.google.com"),howdy
=HYPERLINK("www.facebook.com"),yup
```

Or, with a link label:

```
=HYPERLINK("www.google.com";"Google Homepage"),howdy
=HYPERLINK("www.facebook.com";"Facebook Homepage"),yup
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: If the URL contains a comma, then one more step is needed. Surround the entire formula in double quotes, then escape the double quotes inside the formula:

`"=HYPERLINK(""https://www.google.com/maps/@40.692,-74.087"";""Google Maps"")",howdy`

Answer (score 5):

for me, [@serenesat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/109034/1512) got me in the right direction, but it did not work.

I got the import to Google Sheets to work by doing this:

1. Ensure that the CSV contains the `HYPERLINK` formula, and I used quotes (double, e.g. `"`) for all my data, and then two double-quotes (e.g. `""`) inside the text for a cell to get a quote in the imported data. Example:

   ```
   "Id";"Author";"Link"
   1243;"Google";"=HYPERLINK(""www.google.com"",""Search"")"
   1245;"Google";"=HYPERLINK(""www.google.com"",""Search"")"
   ```
2. After doing the import, in Google Sheets, select the data with the links (rows, columns or all of the data in the sheet) and get Google Sheets to "activate" the imported formulas by selecting ***Format → Number → Automatic***.

That worked for me, hope it helps someone. :-)